# Shiny Plotly event_data Error only with shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am using shiny, plotly and shinyBS as follows to generate a modal pop up with a new plot when a plotly_click event happens on the plot. It works perfectly find when I run locally, and also in the local browser.

However, when I deploy it on the Shiny server, I get this error, and have no idea what it means. Any thoughts?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyBS)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)),
                  y = c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, 3, 1)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, plotlyOutput('scatter')),
  bsModal('boxPopUp', '', '', plotlyOutput('box'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$scatter <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(df1, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = 'markers',
            type = 'scatter', source = 'scatter')
  })
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "scatter"), {
    toggleModal(session, "boxPopUp", toggle = "toggle")
  })
  output$box <- renderPlotly({
    eventdata <- event_data('plotly_click', source = 'scatter')
    validate(need(!is.null(eventdata),
                  'Hover over the scatter plot to populate this boxplot'))
    plot_ly(df2, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'box')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error message is as follows (shown in the Shiny server log for the app):

```
Warning: Error in event_data: attempt to apply non-function
Stack trace (innermost first):
    59: event_data
    58: observeEventExpr
     1: runApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modified version using the modal dialog available in Shiny 0.14.
Tested in RStudio, local browser, [shinyapps](https://altervalter.shinyapps.io/q047/) and on my local instalation of shiny server open source version.

This is the code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)
    library(shinyBS)

    df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
    df2 <- data.frame(x = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)),
                      y = c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, 3, 1)))

    ui <- fluidPage(
            column(6, plotlyOutput('scatter'))
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
            output$scatter <- renderPlotly({
                    plot_ly(df1, x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers',
                            type = 'scatter', source = 'scatter')
            })

            observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "scatter"), {
                    showModal(modalDialog(
                            renderPlotly({
                                    plot_ly(df2, x = x, y = y, type = 'box')
                            }),
                            easyClose = TRUE
                    ))
            })

    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Very interesting and very strange. I did not know that Shiny now has some built-in modal functionality. Good to know and thank you for pointing out. It turns out that once I upgraded Shiny to 0.14 version, even my original code works just fine. So, it must be a problem with the dev version of Shiny I was using 0.13.xyz....I banged my head quite a bit on this and your answer helped. My code is fine as it turns out, although using built-in modals in Shiny seems cleaner.

Comment: When clicking on the same marker twice in a row, the modal doesn't re-open (because event_data hasn't changed). I am banging my head to find a workaround, any ideas?